# How to read/write EC (embedded controller) register with a cpp program

Tags: c++, driver, hardware, bios

I'm trying to write a program to drive a backlit keyboard with a PWM from the laptop EC embedded controller (IT8570E).

In order to do so the program needs to : 
- Catch when user press Fn+F3/F4 to increase/decrease brightness.
- Edit the EC register values to modify the PWM, thus the brightness.

Question is : how to read/write this EC register in a c++ script? I found a program that can do such a thing so I guess it's possible (EC-probe.exe at https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki) and would like to know how to do it with cpp.

Is the EC register included in the windows registers?

(PS: if you also know how to catch when user press keys combinaison I would be interested!)

Note : Originally the laptop does not have backlit keyboard, but have the hardware interface to do so. Other similar models have the backlit keyboard, but it seems the functions to react to the Fn-F3/Fn-F4 combinaisons are included in the BIOS/EC code. Because editing the bios looks really difficult and risky I am investigating the possibility to write a program to handle the backlight directly.

Full project description : https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-Asus-N71JQ-enable-backlit-keyboard

Comment: Your question is unclear and probably operating system specific.

Comment: https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc is free software, GPLv3+ licensed. Study the source code (which has operating system specific parts)

Comment: Do you know what langage this code is? I do not recognize the structure of it.
I also heard of RWEverything software which looks to access EC register and enable writing it. But it crashes my computer on launch...

Comment: No. But https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/blob/master/Windows/NbfcClient/Services/FanControlClient.cs looks like C#

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EmbeddedController](https://github.com/Soberia/EmbeddedController) to read or write EC registers.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#include "ec.hpp"

int main()
{
    EmbeddedController ec = EmbeddedController();

    if (ec.driverFileExist && ec.driverLoaded)
    {
        ec.writeByte(0x30, 0xAA); // Write 0xAA to register 0x30
        BYTE value = ec.readByte(0x30); // Read value of register 0x30
        std::cout << std::hex << (INT)value;
        ec.close(); // Close the resources
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stricto sensu, you cannot read a register in a pure portable standard C++ program (since the C++ specification don't know about registers). Read more about the C++ language, e.g. some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site, some [Introduction to C++ programming](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/), and its [n3337](https://github.com/tpn/pdfs/blob/master/C%2B%2B%20Standard%20-%202012-01-16%20-%20Working%20Draft%20(N3337).pdf) standard for C++11.

However, you could use `asm` statements. They generate code in an implementation specific way.

If you use the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, read its section on [using assembly language with C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html#Using-Assembly-Language-with-C) (most of it apply to C++ also).

If you care about accessing the keyboard on Windows (or some other common [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) such as Android, MacOSX, Linux), you need to use operating system specific primitives (which are outside of the C++ standard).

For Windows, dive in the [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/windows-api-list) documentation.

For Linux, start by reading about its [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) e.g. [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Most Operating Systems are *abstracting* the access to the hardware. Because your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) is [isolated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation) from it.
It is running in [user-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space).

On x86 PCs, be aware of the [SMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode), the BIOS, the UEFI. It probably is managing such magic brightness keys (or interact with your OS [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system))).

> Is the EC register included in the windows registers?

You might confuse some hardware [processor register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) in the keyboard's microcontroller with the [Windows registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry). Despite the phonetic similarity, they are totally unrelated.

PS.  https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc is [**free software**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (GPLv3+ license). Please dive into its source code (which probably has operating system specific parts) and **study the source code** (some Windows-related code, like  [nbfc/Windows/NbfcClient/AppSettings.cs](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/blob/master/Windows/NbfcClient/AppSettings.cs), looks like [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)) code).